# Have a csv file with two columns, if first column contains duplicate, compare second column values against one another

Tags: c#

I have a csv file with two columns; nickname and rank.
What I am trying to achieve is;
if first column contains duplicates,
then compare second column values; store nickname and Rank of the higher value in a new csv file

i.e. imagine this is a csv file:
abc, 8
qwerty, 2
lplo, 5
abc, 15

logic: abc's are duplicated, so compare their values, because 15 is higher than 8, store abc, 15 in a new csv file.

Any suggestions? cannot figure out how to compare the second value

Comment: Have you tried anything so far?

Comment: You can use a dictionary, and restore the value if it is higher

Comment: @DangerZone I can get the duplicates using a foreach i.e. nickname.IndexOf(nick) != nickname.LastIndexOf(nick), but then can't figure out how to compare the second value, how to keep track of it. p.s. I've only started learning c# 2 months ago

Comment: @JoshuaDuxbury don't know what dictionary is yet, will look into it, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated in the comments you can use a dictionary, and store the value if it is higher.

```
    var lines = new List<string>();
    lines.Add("abc, 8");
    lines.Add("qwerty, 2");
    lines.Add("lplo, 5");
    lines.Add("abc, 15");

    var nameAndRanks = new Dictionary<string, int>();
    foreach(var line in lines)
    {
        var values = line.Split(',');
        var name = values[0];
        var rank = int.Parse(values[1]);

        if (nameAndRanks.ContainsKey(name))
        {
            if (nameAndRanks[name] < rank)
            {
                nameAndRanks[name] = rank;
            }
        } else
        {
            nameAndRanks.Add(name, rank);
        }
    }

    foreach (KeyValuePair<string, int> entry in nameAndRanks)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(entry.Key + " : " + entry.Value  );
    }
```

The output of this will be

```
abc : 15
qwerty : 2
lplo : 5
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for this mate

Comment: sorry was going through the code and am having trouble understanding this line:  if (nameAndRanks[name] < rank)
            {
                nameAndRanks[name] = rank;
            } could you explain it please? how are you comparing string to an int?

Comment: I'm not comparing a int to a string. I cast the string to an int "int.Parse(values[1]);" look at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b3h1hf19(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: I am aware of the Parse method, my question was specific to the line: if (nameAndRanks[name] < rank) { nameAndRanks[name] = rank; }. Where name is a string, and rank is an int

Comment: You need to look up how dictionary's work. That name is a string which is used as a key for the dictionary. The dictionary returns an integer

Answer (score 0):

The other solution would be to sort the **CSV** file first with the first column in **ascending** mode and the second column in **descending** mode. this will put the data in the order you want and when comparing the rows just take the first at the top since that is your data row with the highest value and store it in the new **CSV** file.